# php / mysql access denied with select into outfile

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php code:

```
<?php

$hostname="db.";
$database="db..";
$username="db...";
$password="pw...";
$mysql = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

if(!$mysql) 
 echo 'Not conneted to the database...' . mysql_error() ;
else
 echo 'Connected to the database...' ;

// select the appropriate database
$mysqldb = mysql_select_db( $database );
if(!$mysqldb) 
 die('Could not select the database...'  . mysql_error());
else
 echo '<br /><br />Connected to database...<br /><br />' ;

$chk_table_access = 'select * from table_name where 1';
$chk_access = mysql_query($chk_table_access);
echo $chk_table_access . '<br /><br />';
if (!$chk_access) 
 echo 'Could not access table: ' . mysql_error() ;
else
 echo 'Table was accessed..<br /><br />' ;

$backup = 'SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "result.csv" FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY     ENCLOSED BY ';
$backup = $backup . "'" . '"' . "'" ;
$backup = $backup . ' FROM cities WHERE 1';
echo $backup . '<br /><br />';
$bk_success = mysql_query($backup);
if (!$bk_success)
 echo 'The backup was not successful. Reason: '  . mysql_error();
?>
```

The program runs fine on localhost, but when I run it from my web site I get the following error: Access denied for user 'dbo????????'@'%' (using password: YES). The web help is not much help.

I do get the "Table was accessed.." message so I'm accessing the table okay. I do frwite to the directory every day without errors. I understand why it doesn't work in phpMyAdmin. I'm a little stumped. It's also the first question I've asked on this forum although I come here often for help. You guys (ladies included) rock.
Thanks in advance,
Steve

Comment: A couple things to improve your code. When doing a query, you don't need `WHERE 1`. `SELECT * FROM table` will give you everything. Also, to possibly make it easier to read try: 
`'SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "result.csv" FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\' FROM cities'`. You don't have to switch back and forth between " and ' to get the other in your variable.

Comment: Thanks. I tend to include the where 1 clause to denote intent.

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL user apparently lacks the [`FILE` privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file).

Does the MySQL server run on the same machine as the web server? If both servers run on different machines, you can stop right here: Even with `FILE` privilege, the output file would be created on the database server (and would probably inaccessible from the web server).

Comment: This is a possibility. I use a hosted server. How would I check? Steve

Comment: Use `SHOW GRANT` (e.g. in phpMyAdmin) to list all privileges that have been granted to your user.